# Implementing Resolve<Interface[]> and Resolve<IEnumerable<Interface>> in ServiceStack and NinjectIocAdapter

Tags: c#, ninject, servicestack

Hi I'm trying to wire up a Ninject adapter for `ServiceStack`.

Ninject has two resolve methods, get and getall. GetAll should be used when you're trying to resolve lists of things like this:

```
Interface[] arrayOfInterfaces = _kernel.GetAll(typeof(Interface))
```

The problem is the mismatch between this and service stack. I came up with this solution but I'm not happy with it. Any help or ideas on how to better implement this would be much appreciated.

```
    public T Resolve<T>()
    {
        if (typeof (Array).IsAssignableFrom(typeof (T)))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException("Can not resolve array types, use IEnumerable");
        }

        if (typeof(T).IsGenericType && typeof(T).GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))
        {
            var elementType = typeof(T).GetGenericArguments()[0];

            var listOfTypes = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(elementType)) as IList;

            foreach (var o in _kernel.GetAll(elementType))
            {
                listOfTypes.Add(o);
            }
            return (T)listOfTypes;
        }

        return _kernel.Get<T>();
    }
```

Also currently it only supports `IEnumerable<T>` and not `T[]`